# maxpooling function in keras

Tags: keras, tensor, max-pooling

What is the equivalent code for maxpooling2d with ceil mode in keras

So for example in PyTorch we can code like this :
• nn.MaxPool2d(3, stride=2, padding=0, ceil_mode=True)
But in keras, the framework only supports four parameters such as input, window_size, strides, and padding.